# How to access element class's ID one by one using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I been trying to figure out how to get the class's ID using javascript. I have a div class that is executed in PHP, this class can contains many IDs depending on how much data is obtained from the server. I need to check how many ID are there and I also need to get their values such as ID=im_id_1, ID=Im_ID_2.

```
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
   $childID = $row['ID'];
   $parentID = $row['PROD_ID'];
   $childName = $parentID . "_".$childID.".jpg";
   $childImg .= "<img src='../ProductImages/ChildImages/$childName' 
class='imgBotSize' id='$childName'onclick='openNav(this.id)'>";
}
```

At the moment this is how im checking the size of the class, however this is giving me the results in double, if i have 10 items it will alert me with 20. Another issue is I dont know how to get the ID value as I explained above

```
 var img = document.getElementsByClassName("imgBotSize").length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like

```
var ids = [],images = document.querySelectorAll(".imgBotSize"); 
for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) { 
  var id = images[i].id;
  if (id && ids.indexOf(id) ==-1) ids.push(id);
  else console.log("duplicate or missing id",i,id);
}
console.log(ids.length);
```

Comment: yep thanks that is what i was looking for, the way i was doing was returning the length in double, have no idea why. I could just do total = total / 2 but i wasnt very comfortable doing that. with this function i can also get the value of the IDs right? images[i].id will return the id value :)  Thanks for the help. If this question is not dumb enough u mind voting up?

Comment: Im not getting the IDs value with this function, I thought images[i].id would return the value of that specific id. 

UPDATED Nevermind I fixed it, for some weird reason it wasnt giving me the value but it is now.

Comment: UPDATE reason why it wasnt working is because the length of the array starts on images[1]. First time running i set it to image[0] for test purpose and that didnt show any value. Why would image[0] have no value? shouldnt an array length starts from 0 upwards?

Comment: Normally yes......

Comment: Thanks this has helped me carry on now, i was stacked on this for few hours.

Comment: The array did stat at 0, i just forgot that the first div from that class has no ID lol.

Comment: See update for logging

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `fetch_array()` to `fetch_assoc()` will help with returning double results.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

```
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $childID = $row['ID'];
    $parentID = $row['PROD_ID'];
    $childName = $parentID . "_".$childID.".jpg";
    $childImg .= "<img src='../ProductImages/ChildImages/$childName' 
    class='imgBotSize' id='{$childName}' onclick='openNav(this.id)'>";
}
```

&

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('imgBotSize');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i].id);
}
```

That should give you the ID's Available in JavaScript

Comment: `fetch_array` and `fetch_assoc` both return only one array. Can you explain how that change would make a difference with double results?

Comment: thanks I will try that, you mind explaining why assoc instead of array? what are the difference in this case. I can search it up but if u dont mind a quickly explanation please go ahead

Comment: @Don'tPanic `fetch_array()` returns both numeric and associative array. `fetch_assoc()` only returns an associative array.. I believe that answers your question as well @LukeDS

Comment: `fetch_array()` with no argument returns the same values twice, indexed both numerically and associatively, but they're in the same array. It's not two separate arrays.

Comment: @Don'tPanic his issue isn't returning 2 arrays, his issue is returning 1 array containing twice the amount of results.

Comment: @ZanderRootman why would that make any difference here? He's not iterating the result row, he's referring to specific associative keys.

Comment: @Don'tPanic he is iterating over all the results, he's only using the associative keys.

Comment: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: @ZanderRootman yes, he's iterating the results. I meant that he's not iterating over every column in each result row. For each result row that comes out, since he's only referring to the associative keys, the presence of the numeric keys is just irrelevant. It won't increase the count.

Answer (score -2):

Here you will  get array of id's according to the class name

```
 var img_id = document.getElementsByClassName("imgBotSize").id;
```

Comment: No you won't -  getElementsByClassName returns an array of elementS and you cannot get an array of ids without a map or a loop

Comment: Yeah i tried that before posting it. not exactly what Im looking for